# Packaging a python wrapper for large JAR binaries to PyPi

Tags: python, packaging, pypi

I have built a python wrapper for some JAR binaries and I want to distribute it to PyPi. The problem is that the size of these JARs is quite large. They exceed the PyPi limit size of 60MB (the current size is about 200MB or more). What are the best practices for packaging in such cases? I got the following idea but do not know if there is a better practice.

I will save these binaries somewhere and download them with a script in the main **init** function in the wrapper code or during the installation step. This solution seems to be quite good but Could you recommend a good repository to save these binaries? I may suggest DropBox and Google Drive but I feel that they do not fit for this case!

By the way, is it possible to download files during the installation step?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: Just a friendly reminder to click the checkmark on answers to the benefit community members that helped you out.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, move the dependencies out of your package and download them on installation / first use (just be sure you include a progress indicator of some kind so people know what is happening, since it may take some minutes for dependencies that large to be downloaded and you don't want them to think it's hanging.

I'd avoid things like Dropbox or Google Drive (especially Drive) since they are notoriously slow as download mirrors. Instead, try something like [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage). Wrap [CloudFront around it as a CDN too](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) if you want improved latency regionally.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. By the way, I found that I can publish a release in GitHub (I am maintaining this project in GitHub). I published it there then download the binaries from the code. I think this is a reasonable workaround. What do you think?

Comment: I can't speak specifically to GitHub's download speeds by comparison, but I think this is a relatively common practice, linking to your GitHub source or bundled files. I'd say just keep an eye on download speeds and move to a CDN if you get complaints.

Comment: Thanks @alexldaird for your suggestion. Actually, the binaries are hosted now with their authors and they give me a link to consume it. I am depending totally on them now.